# VB.NET: My.Resources.{VARIABLE}

Tags: vb.net, variables, resources

So I can access an image by My.Resources.ImageName..........

But, that is manually-coded.

What I want is to have my image name saved in a variable, lets call it VAR.
VAR = "IMAGE1.png"

So I can do something like

My.Resources.VAR which will return the IMAGE1.png image.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare:

```
Dim imag as Image
imag = My.Resources.foto
PictureBox1.Image = imag
```

That's it, the image (photo) will appear on the PictureBox1

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is an English website. I have translated this for you.