# variable inside object?

Tags: vb.net, variables, resources

How can I put variable in My.Resources, like

```
My.Resources.[var]
```

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  For Each Fe In My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, False, True)
    ProgressBar1.Maximum += 1
    ' MsgBox(Fe.Key)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes _
       (appath & "\bin\" & Fe.Key & ".jpeg", My.Resources.F.Key, True) 'Fe.Key As Variable

  Next
End Sub
```

How can I use Fe.Key in My.Resources?

Comment: what are you trying to get from the resource?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something to add up to your solution since you asked about the key. try this :

```
Dim RSet As Resources.ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, False, True)

If RSet IsNot Nothing Then

    Dim enumerator As IDictionaryEnumerator = RSet.GetEnumerator

    While (enumerator.MoveNext)

     ' You can now use enumerator.key

    End While   

End If
```

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1321942.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Solved .☺

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631142/vb-net-my-resources-variable?rq=1)

Quote :

`My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(var)`