# How to set property to String

Tags: vb.net

So I've got a bunch of pictures in Resources, 3 pictures of Cat, Dog, and Mouse.
I have to ask the user for the animal they want to see, and then display the correct picture.
Currently I have something like this.

```
    Dim animal = InputBox("Enter an animal to show a picture of")
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.animal
```

But I can't set the property to the "animal" string.

How would I do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET: My.Resources.{VARIABLE}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631142/vb-net-my-resources-variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim animalResource As Object = System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(animal)    
PictureBox1.Image = TryCast(animalResource, System.Drawing.Image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`ResourceManager` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
'Get the resource (it exists).
Dim Resource As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(animal)

'Verify that the resource exists and that it is an, or derives from Image.
If Resource IsNot Nothing AndAlso GetType(Image).IsAssignableFrom(Resource.GetType()) Then
    PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(Resource, Image) 'Cast the resource to an image and display it in the picture box.
End If
```