# find text in my.resource.NamesFruit

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the value of the fruit  when i put its name as a String.
(e.g if I put a string data in 
    textbox1.text = "apps", I should get texboxt2.text = 2)

[Here is an image of the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w35Wa.jpg)

I'm trying the code below :

```
if textbox1.text = My.Resources.NamesFruit.Split(New String() {vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) then
```

'Textbox1.text string is "Apps"
???????? I don't know what i'm doing wrong!

Any way to find the text and get the value? Sorry I'm just a little confused.

Comment: Firstly, this has got nothing to do with `My.Resources`.  A `String` is a `String`, regardless of where it comes from.  Secondly, when you add an image and the prompt says "enter image description here", you're supposed to enter the image description there.  As for your question, it's really not clear what you're actually trying to achieve.  Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want the index of the first line that equals a particular `String`?  If so then the aptly named `IndexOf` method is what you want.  It's what you would have found if you'd searched properly.

Comment: You can store them in 'My.Settings.', why doing it in 'My.Resources'?

Comment: If you want to do it using 'My.Settings', I can show how and you will get the same resault as you want.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily : Nonono... `My.Settings` is for settings that you want to be able to modify. One should use `My.Resources` if it is supposed to be an _**immutable**_ value. That's why it's called _Resources_ - because it is a resource to the program, not a setting.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily : If the OP don't want those strings to be modified then `My.Resources` is the way to go. Resources are compiled into the application, whereas `My.Settings` are saved to an external XML file located in `%LocalAppData%\yourCompanyOrAppName\ ` which can be modified at any time and make the program instable.

Comment: ok Find method :  find the text in My.Resources.NamesFruit and in Picture if i enter in the textbox "apps" then i want get value  2  in textbox2 now i guess you understand my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET: My.Resources.{VARIABLE}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631142/vb-net-my-resources-variable)

Comment: no that a different question he asked

Comment: @Deathonly Why not doing it like that : `Try :
             texboxt2.text = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(textBox1.Text)) :
        Catch : End Try`, if id didn't find the string name, it will catch the error and continue without showing anything in `texboxt2`, and if you put `Apps` you will get `2` in texboxt2.

Comment: thanks for reply But Did not work sorry  Mousa Alfhaily

Comment: Mousa Alfhaily Code is wrong I guess

Comment: @Deathonly , Wow, it worked perfectly for me, see [this clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m34kl8l1jis1iza/Untitled.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: Mousa Alfhaily Sorry I Rechecked and Working Fine I guess  My brother make a mistake in Code

Comment: @Deathonly : You're welcome, glad it helped you, please vote up on my comment if it really helped you so it helps others also ;)

Comment: sorry i do not know how to vote up on comment please tell me how to vote up thanks

Comment: @Deathonly ,  To vote up for useful comment, you press the up arrow to the left of the comment.

Comment: i did but it is saying you cant not vote for your own post something